# Obtaining counts for two different conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table `states` as follows:

```
create table states (id int4 unique not null, state int4 not null);
```

I want to get the number of rows in the table that whose state is 1, and the number of rows in the table whose state is 2.  Doing this in two separate queries is straightforward:

```
select count(*) from states where state = 1;
select count(*) from states where state = 2;
```

But it seems silly to go through the whole table twice.  Can someone think of some clever trick that would allow me to get the same information in a single statement and going through the table only once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
    count((state = 1)::integer or null) state_1,
    count((state = 2)::integer or null) state_2
from states
```

or

```
select
    sum((state = 1)::integer) state_1,
    sum((state = 2)::integer) state_2
from states
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `CASE` with an aggregate function:

```
select
  sum(case when state=1 then 1 else 0 end) State1,
  sum(case when state=2 then 1 else 0 end) State2
from states
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [state], COUNT(*) TotalRows 
FROM [Expense].[dbo].[state]
GROUP BY [state]
```

Assume you are using SQL server

Comment: Having clause can be used only if you want to filter the record of grouping fucntion.

Comment: We can use where clause for all other column likeSELECT [state], COUNT(*) TotalRows 
FROM [Expense].[dbo].[state]
WHERE [state] = 1
GROUP BY [state]

Comment: Query 1                                                         SELECT [state], COUNT(*) TotalRows 
FROM [state]
GROUP BY [state]                                                              Query 2                                                            SELECT [state], COUNT(*) TotalRows 
FROM [state]
WHERE [state] = 1
GROUP BY [state]

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from states group by state having state = 1 or state=2;
```

Use SQL group by

Comment: You mean `state = 1 OR state=2`

Comment: And the `where` comes before the `group by`

Comment: you cannot use and , state=1 and state=2 the result is null of course